# Android Firebase Cloud Messaging Notification Summary?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I receive Android Firebase Cloud Messaging standard push notifications. And I can add them to a channel using this `meta-data` tag:

```
 <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
            android:value="foo" />
```

But how can I summarize them if there's more than one. It's easy to do this in code by adding a Notification Group. Is there also a meta tag for adding a group? Or how does it work?

Answer (score 0):

FCM handles it to whom the notification to be sent.

For One-to-One -> you can directly use firebase SDK. You will be needing FCM token to send the notification. Make sure on the token signature change, you update it in the database.

For Group of users -> First you need to subscribe to a certain TOPIC. Then you have to configure it in two ways.

1. Design a backend application that uses firebase SDK. You can configure a custom payload for notification. When a certain event occurs, call the backend API, which notifies FCM to trigger notification with the custom payload to the subscribed devices **(Suggested)**
2. Trigger the event from the Firebase console for the desired topic. **(Not Suggested: Use it only for testing)**

Comment: Thanks for your answer. There's seems to be a misunderstanding. It's not a sending issue. It's a problem on the device. My issue is about grouping FCM messages on the device. Like this: https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/group